# Can we do handwriting detection and reading without the use of neural networks?

Tags: tesseract, handwriting, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to extract text from images where's there's handwriting.
If it's not handwriting ,I get good result using tesseract.

However,I know every handwriting has its own characteristics ,so using a trained model for limited  number of hand writings will not be sufficient to get good results  and thus my question:

Can we do handwriting detection and reading without the use of neuronal networks(machine learning)?